# Why is my clutch not working properly?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, clutch-hydraulics

1990 Toyota pickup 2x4. Once transmission warms up and you go to stop, when I push in the clutch it still moves as if the clutch is released. If you pump the clutch pedal a couple times it will disengage.

Replaced slave cylinder tonight. Problem still exists.

Why is my clutch not working properly? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you provide vehicle information? Also, how did you go about bleeding the clutch?

Comment: 1990 Toyota pickup 2x4 bled through bleeder valve on slave cylinder

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely the master cylinder that needs to be replaced. The brake fluid is either leaking out or by-passing the piston. When you pump the pedal, the clutch will dis-engage but then the pressure from the clutch will force the fluid past the master cylinder piston and the clutch will engage with the pedal held down if the master cylinder needs replacing. Try this and see what happens.